# Terraform for_each with nested resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I am using for_each with local, to create multiples dataset in bigquery.
And another for_each to create table, in previous dataset.

The problem is I have to reference the table with dataset like dataset_ressource.dataset_id.id but I use each.value.dataset1.

So,  it works only if I run "terraform apply" twice

````
locals {
  bq_settings = {
    "${var.dataset1}" = {description = "description dataset 1"},
  } 
} 

locals {
  table_settings = {
    "${var.table1}" = {dataset_id = "dataset1_test", file = "table1.json"},
  } 
} 



resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "map" {
  for_each  = local.bq_settings
  dataset_id                  = each.key
  description                 = each.value.description
  location                    = var.location
  default_table_expiration_ms = 3600000
  
  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "map" {
  for_each  = local.table_settings

  dataset_id = each.value.dataset_id   
  table_id   = each.key
  deletion_protection = false

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }

  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }

  schema = file("${path.module}/schema-bq/${each.value.file}")
  
} 
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works second time, because there is no direct relationship between `google_bigquery_dataset` and `google_bigquery_table`. You can explicitly add such a relationship using [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html):

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "map" {
  for_each  = local.table_settings

  dataset_id = each.value.dataset_id   
  table_id   = each.key
  deletion_protection = false

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }

  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }

  schema = file("${path.module}/schema-bq/${each.value.file}")

  depends_on = [google_bigquery_table.map]  
}
```

Comment: How the local.table_settings looks like?